# How to plot the rownames as dates in a plot?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am using the sp500ret data from rugarch package:

```
library(rugarch)
data(sp500ret)
```

This is (at least I think so) a dataframe, which gives the returns. The rownames are the dates. Now, I want to plot the returns and the dates, so

```
plot(dates,sp500ret)
```

but of course, this does not work, since dates is not specified, but how can I use the rownames as the corresponding dates?

Note: I am not sure about this, but I read something about a xts file. Is this a xts file and how can I plot it in this case?

edit:
I thought about something like this, but it does not work:

```
plot(as.Date(rownames(sp500ret), "%Y%m%d"),sp500ret)
```

2nd edit:
also `plot(rownames(sp500ret),sp500ret[,1])` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the rownames to dates like this:

```
library(rugarch)

data(sp500ret)

my.dates <- strptime(rownames(sp500ret), format="%Y-%m-%d")

plot(my.dates,sp500ret$SP500RET, xlab="Date", las=1, col="steelblue", pch=20)

# Or faster

plot(as.Date(rownames(sp500ret),"%Y-%m-%d"),sp500ret[,1])
```

[image: Date plot]

```
# To specify custom x-axis

par(mar=c(7, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1, bg="white", cex=1.5) # extend margin

plot(my.dates,sp500ret$SP500RET, xlab="", las=1, col="steelblue", pch=20, xaxt="n")

axis.Date(1, at=seq(my.dates[1], my.dates[length(my.dates)], "years"),
          labels=seq(my.dates[1], my.dates[length(my.dates)], "years"),
          format= "%Y-%m-%d", las=2)
```

[image: Date plot with custom x-axis]

Comment: I now also found: plot(as.Date(rownames(sp500ret),"%Y-%m-%d"),sp500ret[,1]) this seems also to work?

Comment: @StatTistician It makes the labels of the y-axis horizontal. I just like it better as I find it easier to read. See the documentation [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html).

Comment: thanks, but why is your default plot in blue and pch=18 ? (I will accept your answer in two minutes, when I am allowed to do it)

Comment: @StatTistician This is not my default plot. I have edited my answer and it now contains the code I used to produce the plot.

Comment: one further question: How can I get a more detailed x axis? So e.g. for each year the number (and not every 5th year)?

Comment: @StatTistician Have a look at `at` in `?axis`.